# Text elements using material3 take up more space than material2. How to set text height globally to match material2?

Tags: flutter

It seems with material3 the height of the Text was increased, meaning even though I use the same `fontSize` before and after the update to material3, the text takes up more space. In my case, this leads to overflow errors in some cases.

I found I can fix this when setting `height: 1` of the `TextStyle` but to do so, I would need to set this to each text element individually.

Is there a way I can use the "old spacing"? Meaning setting the height of the text elements globally to match the height of the text elements from material2?

Answer (score 2):

The better way is to set the height globally via the theme.

Add this to your theme:

```
textTheme: const TextTheme(
      bodyLarge: TextStyle(height: 1),
      bodyMedium: TextStyle(height: 1),
      bodySmall: TextStyle(height: 1),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) in builder of MaterialApp:

Example:

```dart
            MaterialApp(
                home: const HomeScreen(),
                builder: (context, child) => DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: const TextStyle(height: 1),
                  child: child!,
                ),
              ),
```